# $S(\Omega \sqcap A)=S(\Omega)\sqcap A$ Halmos Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble grasping the proof of theorem E, section 5, chapter 1 in Halmos' *Measure Theory*.

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and $\Omega$ a family of subsets of of $X$. Given $A\subset X$, denote by $\Omega \sqcap A$ the class of all sets of the form $E \cap A$ with $E \in \Omega$. Further, denote by $S(\Omega)$ the $\sigma $-ring generated by $\Omega$.

**Theorem**: If $\Omega$ is any class of sets and if $A$ is any subset of $X$, then $$S(\Omega \sqcap A)=S(\Omega)\sqcap A$$

At the start of the proof he lets $\mathscr{F}$ be the class of all sets of the form $B \cup (C\setminus A)$, where $B \in S(\Omega \sqcap A)$ and $C \in S(\Omega)$.

He then goes on to claim that "it is is to verify that $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-ring". **My question is:** why is $\mathscr{F}$ closed under differences? If I take two sets in $\mathscr{F}$ I can't seem to realize why their difference is of the form of a set in $\mathscr{F}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F_0=B_0\cup(C_0\setminus A)$ and $F_1=B_1\cup(C_1\setminus A)$, where $B_i \in S(\Omega \sqcap A)$ and $C_i \in S(\Omega)$ for $i=0,1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
F_0\setminus F_1&=\big(B_0\cup(C_0\setminus A)\big)\setminus\big(B_1\cup(C_1\setminus A)\big)\\
&=\Big(B_0\setminus\big(B_1\cup(C_1\setminus A)\big)\Big)\cup\Big((C_0\setminus A)\setminus\big(B_1\cup(C_1\setminus A)\big)\Big)\\
&=\Big((B_0\setminus B_1)\cap\big(B_0\setminus(C_1\setminus A)\big)\Big)\cup\Big(\big(C_0\setminus(A\cup B_1)\big)\cap(C_0\setminus C_1)\Big)\\
&=\Big((B_0\setminus B_1)\cap B_0\Big)\cup\Big(\big(C_0\setminus A\big)\cap (C_0\setminus C_1)\Big)\\
&=(B_0\setminus B_1)\cup(C_0\setminus C_1)\setminus A\\
&\in \mathscr{F}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The step from the third to the fourth line uses the fact that $B_i\subseteq A$ for $i=0,1$.

Comment: @Reveillark: My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

I think the unstated part of this is that $S(\Omega\cap A)$ should be $S_A(\Omega\cap A)$ i.e. the $\sigma$-ring generated with respect to the set $A$ not the whole set $X$